# Snowflake Timezone

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a small doubt regarding time zone in snowflake
Like different region contains different default time zone or it is the same for all irrespective of the region?
Eg:
SF account in Australia will have US time zone or Australia time zone as its default.

If there is any proof for the answer kindly attach the documentation page too for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default timezone is set to America/Los_Angeles irrespective where the account is located.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timezone)

Comment: But I am still confused how come a user having Australia based snowflake account and snowflake is providing the time zone of USA

Comment: @VenkataramananSundaresan The parameter can be changed by the customer. It was deployed like that since some parameters have a default value and for this one the default was chosen to be US Pacific. Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: No that is okay just want to clarify because say for example if a client creates a task or something in their account which is some other region other that US basically their nearby region they will eventually come up with this question

Answer (score 0):

You can check timezone with

```
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE '%TIMEZONE' IN SESSION;
```

And change timezone for session with

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Rome';
```

However I'm getting different result for different utility functions (outside Web UI)

```
SELECT localtime(), localtimestamp(), current_time(), current_timestamp(), sysdate();
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using DBeaver. That does not display the local time zone for TIMESTAMPLTZ data types unless you change the setting "Disable date/time formatting" in the DBeaver data source settings.